# parameter passing in java script in access a url?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
i am designing a  project in **phonegap** with android.
```

I have two text boxes which ids are id and password. now i want to know how can i send the values of these text boxes using url.

```
for one parameter i have done it successfully as follows.

**url: 'http://192.168.1.214/sample/dologin.php?id='+id**

but i dont know how can i send two argument. second argument is password. Please suggest me what should i do..?
```

Comment: -1 This question shows a lack of research, please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'http://192.168.1.214/sample/dologin.php?id='+id+'&password='+yourpassword
```